# MySQL(RDBMS) for order/shipping info and MongoDB(NoSQL) for product info. Can this work?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, nosql, e-commerce, rdbms

I am trying to build an integrated commerce backend, where multiple ecommerce channels can be connected. This service has two main functions:
1. It brings all the orders from all the connected commerces together.
2. Manager registers the new product to our service once. Then our service registers this product to all the connected commerces.

I am planning to use MySQL as my main database. But, when it comes to product info, Im not sure if MySQL(or any other RDBMS) would be a clever choice. Because each commerce most likely require some other new info. I dont want to add columns or make new table every time we add new commerces to our platform.

So I thought I could use MongoDB( NoSQL) when related to products and use MySQL when related to orders. Would this be a good idea? Im worried about querying limits and any other potential problems which I might encounter.

By the way I am using node.js for my backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using more than one DB is not a bad idea at all, infact it becomes a necessity when your application is growing. Clearly, you cannot choose MySql for products as performing alter table at every commerce addition is not a good option. And mongodb is a good choice for such data, but then querying becomes difficult and slow in mongo.
What I would suggest is to not worry about the database right from the start. Go with something that you are more comfortable with and then based on how your app grows take further decisions. Write your code in such a way that it's easy to replace the db at any point of time, because it's very difficult to know how the app would grow in the near future and what feature will be required more.

Comment: Can you give me a comment about this: lets say the product info is a complex JSON file. With MySQL I can save it as `text` and with MongoDB I can save it as a `document`. I guess both ways can work. But, I heard MongoDB has strength in Big Data. Well in this case although schema less part of MongoDB can be very useful, product info will not going to be "big data". What would you prefer?

Comment: It's true that MongoDB is good for handling big data because of sharding and other things but it is not that good because of single master and multiple slave concept (although reads are pretty good). It's true that scaling is tough in MySQL but there is a reason why relational databases cannot be replaced by NoSQL, as query speed is really good with them. I would still prefer MongoDB for product info, because you mentioned that it is a complex JSON, so storing it as a document in MongoDB sounds like a better option to me. And since you don't expect it to grow big, querying should be easy.